# Why is the "R.java" file automatically deleted in Android?

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I am writing an Android application. One of the automatically generated files is "R.java". Sometimes this is deleted automatically. Why is "R.java" automatically deleted?

Answer (score 2):

R.java is generated automatically. You should never edit it directly. Place your resources in the relevant project folders and let the SDK generate the file for you (as part of the compilation process)

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromCode
R.java is linking your resources with static variables so you can easily access them from your code. R.java is generated automatically from aapt tool so if you do any changes manually they will be discarded after regeneration.